# Ionic/Cordova plugin error while trying to add a plug in

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, appsee

I'm trying to add [Appsee](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/ionic) plug-in to my ionic 2 app.But when I try to install it using the following command:

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appsee

I'm getting the below error in my terminal

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

Has there been an update to Ionic that's giving me this error?

**edit**

Upon n00b's suggestion I ran npm init, and npm install which is giving me [this](https://ibb.co/jVoEnw) error.

Comment: are you sure your internet connection was good when you ran the command? this is weird

Comment: yea, my internet is pretty good. I haven't had any issues.

Comment: check the connection by running this command line  `telnet registry.npmjs.org 443` :)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not an ionic issue. more likely an NPM issue. 
1. make sure you don't have a proxy. if you have a proxy you should set the proxy for NPM 
2. try if you can install any other packages. by doing these commands

```
npm init
npm install @angular/core --save
```

Comment: you're right it was a npm error. I ran the commands above and got this error (https://ibb.co/jVoEnw) after running npm install